# YouTubeの検索結果､関連動画やコメント､好評価ボタン､登録ボタンのandroidアプリでの利用について｡

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

私は今､Androidで動くYouTubeプレーヤーを作ろうと考えています｡  そこで質問なのですが､YouTube動画を再生するにはYouTube Player APIを使えばよいとのことですが､検索結果や関連動画､コメント､高評価ボタン､登録ボタンは取得できるのでしょうか｡  できればUIを公式のYouTubeアプリに近づけたいので､もし出来るならば､方法を教えて頂きたいです｡
また,参考になるサイト等あれば教えていただけると幸いです｡

YouTube DATA APIを使えば良いのかと考えたのですが､これはAndroidアプリでつかえるのでしょうか?

また､ある期間､例えば1時間､1週間､1ヶ月等､に同じ検索ワードで検索された動画をランキング表示することはできますか?

Comment: YouTube Data API のライブラリは、 Android で使用可能です。

Comment: タイトルに対して質問の内容が多岐に渡っているのが気になります。まずリファレンス（日本語です！）を読んで何ができるのか把握しましょう。

Comment: アドバイス有難うございます｡  リファレンスを参照したいと思います｡